# How do solar panels affect the short circuit fault currents of a network?

Tags: current, solar-energy, fault

As title suggests, I'm trying to find out how adding PV, both residential and solar farms, have an effect on the short circuit fault current of a network.

I wasn't given much info to go off, so I am going to say that it would be an inverter fault. This is for more of a general case, so if there is a rule of thumb for the fault levels that would be great.

If not, looking mainly at fault levels that might be seen at a residential setting, as well as at 150MW plant.

If the inverter fault is smaller than some other fault associated with a solar pannel, please let me know.

Comment: under what conditions? inverter failure? GIS?  what size of farm? You need to read more to define the question better.

Comment: Updated the question. From what I've been seeing the fault current is normally 1 to 5 times the rated current for the inverter (most sources are saying between 1 to 2) . They have also been saying that because there is no spinning mass behind it the faults are often very short lived and in general do not have a large effect on a system.

Comment: In the UK, you can find the relevant specification for domestic solar installations by searching for G83/2 - this includes safety test limits including short circuit testing.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the solar panel characteristics, you will see that the short-circuit current of the panel is not much above the current at the maximum power point. The inverter will probably have capacitors on the DC side to accommodate the reactive volt-ampere demand of the load. The stored energy in those capacitors could contribute to the prospective short-circuit current, but the current level would be limited electronically by the inverter. If the inverter fails, it would not be able to supply current to a short-circuit on the AC side. It might represent an additional short circuit path carrying current supplied by the solar panel.

With respect to the comment, prospective fault current that is very much above 1 PU would be electronically limited. Any failure of the electronic limit would essentially create another short-circuit path. The capacitors would be like a spinning mass, but isolated from the distribution system by the inverter.

Answer (score 0):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXkxQQ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Power grid Impedances use Ohm's Law like this using per unit (p.u.) as a ratio or % of rated Voltage / rated current.  Thus the short circuit fault current compared to rated current becomes the inverse of Zo.

Whereas the ratio of source/load can be estimate by the ratio of voltage drop  from source/load.

The voltage disturbance of two voltage source operating in tandem with a short fault from one depends on their respective impedance ratios.

If both sources have the same impedance, then a fault from one drops the voltage of the other by 50%.  If the solar array is only 1% of the grid it is connected to, then the impact is 1%.  but if the fault is not the inverter but the power line wires this is much lower than the Zo of the inverter.

HV generation sources impedances usually start at 12% and through distribution lower to 8%, which implies the ratio of rated/fault currents.

> A PV farm might have a Zo p.u. of 10% which for a home unit might only be 0.1% of the Zo of the grid it is connected to.

*But for something completely different,* with Audio power Amps with negative feedback the source impedance can be as low as 1% to 0.1% of the load. However this does not imply short circuit current is 100x ~ 1000x.  Because the negative feedback gain lowers output impedance, the feedback is suppressed by the output being shorted, the output impedance rises with a short circuit.